# How to fix "Ignored duplicated keys" in message

Tags: ruby, soap, savon

I'm using Savon to test some WSDL SOAP services, and some of the services need  duplicated keys/values in the message. For example the "product" value inside the "products" array:

```
@client.call(
  :create_template, message: {
    :item => [{
      'promotion_id'      => "1",
      'code_is_unique'    => "0",
      'name'          => "qasusc1",
      'description'     => "Automation suscription",
      'basecode'        => "qasusc1",
      'total_redemptions'   => "30",
      'valid_from'      => "2016-12-12 00:00:00",
      'valid_to'        => "2017-12-12 00:00:00",
      'duration_quantity'   => "1",
      'duration_unit'     => "M",
      'operator_code'     => "NAME",
      'initial_quantity'    => "30",
      :products => [{
        :product => [{
          'id'          => "3",
          'off_percentage'    => "100",
          'quantity'        => "1"
        }],
        :product => [{
          'id'          => "4",
          'off_percentage'    => "100",
          'quantity'        => "1"
        }]
      }],
      :lists => [{
        'list'          => "1"
      }],
      :promotion_rules => [{
        :promotion_rule => [{
          'code'    => "HAS_PAYMENT_GATEWAY_RULE",
          'value'   => "1"
        }]
      }]
    }]
  }
)
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
tests/suites_soap/test_soap.rb:840: warning: duplicated key at line 22 ignored: :product
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[mcve]". We need to see the minimum code and input data that demonstrates the problem. Please add code that will run, and reduce the input to the smallest input possible that continues to result in the message. This helps us as we don't have to write a test harness or reduce the data, which slows answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot duplicate a key inside a hash, period.

`{ a: 1, a: 2 }` will *always* be equal to `{a: 2}`.

According to [this issue](https://github.com/savonrb/savon/issues/45), you should use an array to represent duplicated keys in Ruby form:

```
:products => [{
  :product => [
    {
      'id'                    => "3",
      'off_percentage'        => "100",
      'quantity'              => "1"
    },
    {
      'id'                    => "4",
      'off_percentage'        => "100",
      'quantity'              => "1"
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! that worked flawlessly and I understanded the real problem with it!